# How to display a geometric object from Python code in a Rmarkdown document?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

I would like to have a point displayed (like [in this tutorial](https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/L1/geometric-objects.html#point)) in my rmarkdown document after knitting.

Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Reprex"
output: html_document
---

```{python}
# Import necessary geometric objects from shapely module
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon

# Create Point geometric object(s) with coordinates
point1 = Point(2.2, 4.2)

point1
```
````

With this code, I only get the following output:

`## <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x0000000026EEA0B8>`

How can I have the image of the point displayed instead?

Also, I am interested to display it in the viewer/plot pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, not sure if this is crucial, but, [following the documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/r_markdown.html#engine-setup-1), we need to add this chunk first:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(reticulate)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```
````

What you want to get is Jupyter-specific functionality. I was able to reproduce it only by converting the point(s) to pure SVG via [`_repr_svg_()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) function:

````py
```{python}
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint

point1 = Point(2.2, 4.2)
point2 = Point(7.2, -25.1)
point3 = Point(9.26, -2.456)
point3D = Point(9.26, -2.456, 0.57)

multipoints = MultiPoint([point1, point2, point3, point3D])
svg = multipoints._repr_svg_()

# or, in your case

svg = point1._repr_svg_()
```
````

Then displaying it with R chunk:

````
```{r}
htmltools::HTML(py$svg)
```
````

I tried doing it on Python-side only (calling `r.HTML()`), which will only result in textual output.

Note that this will result in the following warning:

```
sys:1: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
```

But you can ignore it, it still draws the points:

[image]
[image]

Full code:

````
---
title: "Reprex"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(reticulate)
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```

```{python}
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint

point1 = Point(2.2, 4.2)
point2 = Point(7.2, -25.1)
point3 = Point(9.26, -2.456)
point3D = Point(9.26, -2.456, 0.57)

multipoints = MultiPoint([point1, point2, point3, point3D])
svg = multipoints._repr_svg_()

# or, in your case

svg = point1._repr_svg_()
```

```{r}
htmltools::HTML(py$svg)
```
````